# How many facet fields can one query in a single solr query? Is there any limit for number of facet fields?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I would like to limit number for facet fields to be requested from one of our API's, one way to do is to code it as per the limit I require.

I was wondering whether there is any parameter that solr provides to limit the total number of requested facet fields.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context of the facet application. But in most cases I think doing it at coding time would be better.

As far as I know Solr doesn't have a 'facet limit' functionality, but let's say it does and you limit it to 10. If you send a request with 15 facets to Solr, it could potentially ignore the last 5 facets and just return results using the first 10, without any indication that it has cut off some of the facets. It's best that Solr returns results that exactly match what you want.

So handle excess facets in your code accordingly before sending it to Solr.